# Creating Message Queue with the help of threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, message-queue

I am learning about creating threads and how they interact with each other, so I thought to create a simple message queue.

The model I am following is this:

[image: diagram]

Now I am kinda stuck on an issue I am facing. Both threads wants to print something, but they overlap with each other. My thought was maybe adding a sleep to the client thread would make it work, and it was a success.

My question now would be, is my approach a good solution, and is there another way to fix this issue. Also any feedback on code or improvements would be appreciated.

---

Code:

```
#define MAX_SIZE    1024
#define QUEUE_NAME  "/MQ"
#define MSG_STOP    "END"

void *server() {

    mqd_t mq;
    struct mq_attr attr;
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE + 1];
    int state = 1;

    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 100;
    attr.mq_msgsize = MAX_SIZE;
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

    mq = mq_open(QUEUE_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0644, &attr);
    while (state) {

        mq_receive(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, NULL);
        if (!strncmp(buffer, MSG_STOP, strlen(MSG_STOP))) {
            state = 0;
            printf("chat closing\n");
        } else {
            printf("Msg reached: %s\n", buffer);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *client() {

    mqd_t mq;
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
    mq = mq_open(QUEUE_NAME, O_WRONLY);
    int state = 1;

    printf("To exit the chat type END \n");
    while (state) {
        printf("chatting: ");
        fflush(stdout);

        memset(buffer, 0, MAX_SIZE);
        fgets(buffer, MAX_SIZE, stdin);
        if (!strncmp(buffer, MSG_STOP, strlen(MSG_STOP))) {
            mq_send(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, 0);
            state = 0;
        } else {
            mq_send(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, 0);
            printf("Msg sent: %s\n", buffer);
            sleep(0.9);

        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pthread_t t1, t2;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &server, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &client, NULL);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
```

**Result without sleep added:**

```
To exit the chat type END 
chatting: test
Msg sent: test

chatting: Msg reached: test

test2
Msg sent: test2

chatting: Msg reached: test2

END
chat closing
```

**With sleep added:**

```
To exit the chat type END 
chatting: test
Msg sent: test

Msg reached: test

chatting: test2
Msg sent: test2

Msg reached: test2

chatting: END
chat closing
```

Comment: Use a mutex to prevent two threads accessing the same resource (`stdout`) at the same time.

Comment: Unrelated: What is the signature of the `sleep` version you are using? It's very common that the argument is an integer of some sort, in which case `sleep(0.9)` becomes `sleep(0)`.

Comment: Related: How can that even compile? Your `server` and `client` functions have the wrong signature. `void *(void *)`` would be the correct one.

Comment: the sleep should be (1) typo, for the functions that how some guide on youtube showed it so it might be wrong but it runs without any warning or errors using eclipse

Comment: You probably want `flockfile` and `funlockfile`. For an example, see my answer: [C Logging Function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/249053/89044)

Answer (score 1):

> My thought was maybe adding a sleep to the client thread would make it work.

Sometimes adding a `sleep` call will make a multi-threaded program work the way you expect it to work, but in most programming languages/libraries/operating systems, a `sleep` is never *guaranteed* to make anything work.

Don't be fooled. If your program has a threading-related bug, and `sleep` *seems* to fix it, probably all it's really done is made the bug much harder to reproduce. Maybe you've made it so hard to reproduce that, *for your purposes,* it might as well not be there at all anymore. But just try shipping that code to a customer, and *then* see what happens.

Do not depend on `sleep` to coordinate the behavior of threads when money or your reputation are on the line.

> Is there another way to fix this issue?

Any time you want to make sure that two threads do not interfere with each other when they try to use some shared resource (e.g., `stdout` in this case,) the first thing you should think of is to use a [*mutex*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3p.html).

A mutex can be in either one of two states which I will call "locked" and "available." (Sometimes they have other names.) It has two useful properties:

1. No two threads will ever be allowed to lock the mutex at the same time. If one thread tries to lock it when another thread already *has* locked it, then the first thread will be forced to wait until the other thread releases the mutex.
2. The changes that one thread makes to shared variables while it has a mutex locked are guaranteed to be visible to any other thread after the second thread subsequently locks the same mutex. Some people call this "synchronization," and a mutex is one way of achieving it. If two threads access the same variables without any synchronization, that's a recipe for bugs that can be hard to reproduce, and sometimes extremely hard to find.

Comment: in your opinion where would I lock and unlock for it not to access the `stdout` ?